# Distributing windows media player 11 with .net based application

Tags: .net, installation, windows-media-player, redistributable

I am developing a WPF based application using .NET 3.5 SP1, which required windows media player 11 to be installed on end user machine. For pain free installation I want that the setup should handle everything. Is there any redistributable package of WMP 11 is available?

In other words, What is the best option to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just get the suitable version(s) of the setup from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/download/AllDownloads.aspx) (remember to account for 32 bit vs 64 bit and for various languages). Then follow the instructions on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758057%28VS.85%29.aspx) page for installing it silently.

You'd have to make sure that the license allows you to do this though according to your circumstances.